# How to save my output to csv as column wise

Tags: python, pandas

Here first function has to return to first  `col1` and second function has to return second column  `col2` in the data.csv file. I wrote one code but not able to save.

```
def func1(testvalue):
    json_d = {"task_id": "user_uid","data": {"document1":testvalue}} 
    response = requests.post("https://example.net/document",headers=headers,json=json_d)
    my_data1 = response.text
    file = open("data.csv","a+")
    file.write(my_data1)
    file.close()
    my_data = json.loads(my_data1)
    result = {'bool':my_data['data']}
    return result

def func2(testvalue):
    test = {"data": {"doc1":testvalue}} 
    response = requests.post("https://example.net/v3/docs",headers=headers,json=test)
    my_data2 = response.text
    file = open("data.csv","a+")
    file.write(my_data2)
    file.close()
    my_data = json.loads(my_data2)
    result = {'bool':my_data['data']}
    return result
```

`df['res'] = df['test'].apply(func1)` >> it will save the `file.write(my_data1)` to first column and `df['test'].apply(func1)` will save `file.write(my_data2)` to the second column of the data.csv

Comment: I recommend using context managers to handle files. Can you be more specific in your question? What does _but not able to save_ mean? Can you share what the data looks like? Is this reproducible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution

If I understand your requirement correctly, you want to save each column as a separate `.csv` file. You could do this easily using [**`pandas.DataFrame.to_csv`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html#pandas-dataframe-to-csv).

Now assume that you want to save one column at a time to **ONE SINGLE `.CSV`** file. In that case, you could simply combine the column data stored in each of the files you create as I showed below and save that as a separate `csv` file with all the information. If you would like, you could also delete the individual files after you combine them.

> Here we create a dummy dataframe with columns `x` and `y` and then write each of them to a `.csv` file of that column using `pandas.DataFrame.to_csv` as follows and finally check the list of files created at the `output_path`.

```py
# Imports
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import os

# Make dummy dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': np.arange(10), 'y': np.arange(10)**2})

# Define your output_path
output_path = os.getcwd() + '/output'
if not os.path.exists(output_path):
    os.makedirs(output_path)

# Write individual CSV files for each column
for col_name in df.columns:
    df[col_name].to_csv(path_or_buf=os.path.join(output_path, col_name + '.csv'), index=False)

# Check/Enlist contents in the output-path
print(sorted(os.listdir(output_path)))
```

**Output**:

```
['x.csv', 'y.csv']
```

> ## Reading in each column and together writing to a single CSV file

```py
files = sorted(os.listdir(output_path))
df2 = pd.DataFrame()
for i, filename in enumerate(files):
    if filename not in ['out.csv']:
        col_name = filename.replace('.csv', '')  
        print('filename: {} | col_name: {}'.format(filename, col_name))  
        col_df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(output_path, filename))    
        if i==0:
            df2.reindex(index = col_df.index)
        df2[col_name] = col_df['0']

# Write all columns to a single CSV
df2.to_csv(os.path.join(output_path, 'out.csv'))
```

Comment: not separate csv file same csv file different columns

Comment: can you update on my code, i know by adding some logics

Comment: You need to write each column first to a separate csv file. And once you are done doing that, then read them into a dataframe and save it to a single CSV as I showed above.